# R Statistics, trying to check is nrow of tables == a certain number but code messes up if table has no rows

Tags: r, null, logical-operators

I have a big `ifelse` statement looking at a bunch of tables to see which table has a certain number of rows.

However, not all tables have rows. When a table with no rows runs though a code like `nrow(table1) == 10` then it returns `logical(0)` instead of `FALSE`. How can I make it so this situation returns `FALSE` instead?

Some example code is shown below.

```
nrowtest <- NULL
nrow(nrowtest) == 10
```

I want it to return `FALSE` instead of `logical(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NA == 10` will always give `NA` and `NULL == 10` will give `logical(0)`. Just add conditions to the `if()` or `ifelse()`:

```
!is.null(nrow(nrowtest)) && nrow(nrowtest) == 10
```

Comment: One one is good but I believe you only need to test the number of rows of the variable once. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There's also `NROW`, in capitalised form:

```
nrowtest <- NULL
NROW(nrowtest) == 10
#[1] FALSE

nrowtest <- table(1:10,1:10)
NROW(nrowtest) == 10
#[1] TRUE
```